# How would I create something similar like this in AngularJS

Tags: javascript, angularjs, html, angularjs-directive

Having a hard time grasping AngularJs.. How would you build something like this simple textfields and animations in AngularJS? I had been looking into using directives but it just isn't adding up to me much. I had been trying to base this from what I learned online but was not having much luck

http://codepen.io/yusufbkr/pen/RPBQqg

HTML:

```
<div class="materialContainer">
```

```
  <div class="title">LOGIN</div>

  <div class="input">
     <label for="name">Username</label>
     <input type="text" name="name" id="name">
     <span class="spin"></span>
  </div>

  <div class="input">
     <label for="pass">Password</label>
     <input type="password" name="pass" id="pass">
     <span class="spin"></span>
  </div>

  <div class="button login">
     <button><span>GO</span> <i class="fa fa-check"></i></button>
  </div>

  <a href="" class="pass-forgot">Forgot your password?</a>
```

```
  <div class="title">REGISTER</div>

  <div class="input">
     <label for="regname">Username</label>
     <input type="text" name="regname" id="regname">
     <span class="spin"></span>
  </div>

  <div class="input">
     <label for="regpass">Password</label>
     <input type="password" name="regpass" id="regpass">
     <span class="spin"></span>
  </div>

  <div class="input">
     <label for="reregpass">Repeat Password</label>
     <input type="password" name="reregpass" id="reregpass">
     <span class="spin"></span>
  </div>

  <div class="button">
     <button><span>NEXT</span></button>
  </div>
```

just use the codepen link ( http://codepen.io/yusufbkr/pen/RPBQqg ), stackoverflow won't let me input the rest of the code...

Thanks! Any help would be incredible

Comment: Why not using ng-animations? Take a look a this  https://docs.angularjs.org/guide/animations

Answer (score 2):

I'm just learning Angular myself.  From what I know, you're on the right track to be thinking of directives for swapping out interactive parts of the DOM.  I suspect you'll also be needing ui-router for dealing with the widget outcomes (I hear it's the industry standard, vs the built-in ngRouter).

I'm partly writing this out to make sure I understand it, so I hope other, more knowledgeable people will come by and answer any questions you have about it (or point out where I'm misundertanding something.)

So you bring the webpage into the Angular world by, for instance, making the `<html></html>` tags into `<html ng-app="yourApp"></html>`.  The unchanging html that will be the same on every view is in the index.html file.  Put the html for the boxes is in another html file, say box.html.  On the index.html file in the place where you want to have your boxes appear, put `<div ui-view></div>`.  The ui-view connects to ui-router.  Down at the bottom of the index.html right before closing the body tag, put
`<script src="lib/angular/angular.js"></script>`
`<script src="lib/angular-ui-router/release/angular-ui-router.js"></script>`
`<script src="app/app.js"></script>`.

In app.js, you put something like,

```
    angular.module('yourApp', [
     'yourApp.box',
     'ui.router'
    ])
    .config(function($stateProvider, $urlRouterProvider, $httpProvider) {
      $urlRouterProvider
        .otherwise('/signin/child');

      $stateProvider
        .state('box', {
          url: '/signin',
          templateUrl: 'app/box/box.html',
          controller: 'BoxController'
        })
        .state('box.child', {
          url: '/child',
          template: '<span>{{ definedProperty }}</span>'
        });
      })
    });
```

Starting at the top, you name angular, call its module function, and give it the parameters ('theNameYouChose', ['dependencies','required'])

In the config bit there, you're telling it about dependencies config needs.  $stateProvider and $urlRouterProvider are ui-router things, and $httpProvider is, I believe, an angular thing that is still necessary.

In the urlRouterProvider, you're providing the default address the website goes to:  in this case it  happens to be a template within a template, /signin from the signin state, and /child from the specifics pasted into signin

In the states, you are giving names and properties to the URLs that will be part of your app:  like, if someone goes to index.html/signin, the 'signin' state is summoned.

The template within a template might be how you'd get the box variability that you're looking for.  In box.html you will have another `<div ui-view></div>` and that's where the varying thing described in 'signin.child' gets put in.

box.html is also the place you put your specially created html tags, the ones you will make with the directive.  I'll talk through those below.

The parent template, 'signin', talks about BoxController.  Let's say you built that in box.js.  It would look like this:

```
    angular.module('yourApp.box', [])

    .controller('BoxController', function ($scope) {
      $scope.definedProperty = 'reRegPass',
      $scope.arrayOfObjects = [{prop: 'red'},{prop: 'blue'}]
    })

    .directive('specificBox', function(){
      return {
        restrict: 'EA',
        templateUrl: 'app/box/box-guts.html',
        replace: true,
        scope: {
          source: '='
        },
        link: function(scope, element, attribute) {
          element.on('click', function() {
            alert('Functionality in specificBox is working');
          }
        }
      }
    });
```

The first line is again summoning angular module, and then naming it: note we already listed this, 'yourApp.box', as a requirement in app.js.  Then we have the controller-naming function, and the appearance of specific properties in their $scope.

The directive is taking the more useful of the two forms a directive can take.  They can either return functions (with signatures like the one in .link), or they can return objects that describe new HTML entities.  This one is named specificBox, which Angular will translate into `<specific-box></specific-box>`.  This object (technically called a 'directive definition object') can be translated into HTML tags because of the restrict property...  'E' is for element.  'A' is for attribute.  I don't know how something that can be an element could also be an attribute, but having both options works, so I'm going with it.  (Maybe for your various signin boxes you want a directive that has just 'A' to make new types of attributes.)

You put these specifically-crafted tags into box.html, and everything in box-guts.html will be between those tags...  In fact, replacing those tags because of the replace: true.

The .link property is where you would put a function that would do something interesting to that element; turn it red if clicked, whatever.  I have an alert example.  Uses jQuery Lite for events.

The .scope property is odd.  I believe if left off, the specific-box stuff would have the same controller as box (ie, BoxController), with box's scope and dependencies.  But here, instead, we're making an isolate scope.  box-guts will not depend on anything or have access to anything built before.  How will it get interesting changeable data, then..?  Every property in the scope object becomes an attribute on specific-box.

The '=' means that you will pass it objects from somewhere, and they will have 2-way data binding (changes made in box-guts will be reflected in the object collection in your app).  Other options are '@', one-way data binding, which means you're passing box-guts a string or something that, if it changes in the DOM, you don't care to reflect in your app; or '&' to give it a function from a controller somewhere else in your app.

So ultimately, in box.html, you will have something like

```
    <div class="box-holder">

      <div ui-view></div>

      <specific-box source="thing" ng-repeat="thing in arrayOfObjects"></specific-box>

    </div>
```

Like I said above, ask questions and maybe we can sort this out.

Comment: First of, gotta thankyou so much for such a long explanation.. you really helped me. Thank you for that. So basically I would still create the box normally in the box-guts.html like before with the css, and then use the directive to program the js logic??